# RecyclerView and CardView implement onClick

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have a bunch of values that get pulled from mysql database and then are displayed in cardview using RecyclerView. This works great.

I want to now implement onClick on each item that is pulled, can anyone please point me in the right direction? I'm looking at being able to click on a card and have another view open with the "image", "name" and "publisher" values that are pulled from mysql using json, problem is I don't know how to pass these values onto a new activity, especially the values being pulled from mysql.

**Movies.java**

```
public class Movies extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerView.OnScrollChangeListener {

//Creating a List of superheroes
private List<SuperHero> listSuperHeroes;

//Creating Views
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

//Volley Request Queue
private RequestQueue requestQueue;

//The request counter to send ?page=1, ?page=2  requests
private int requestCount = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.movies);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //Initializing Views
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL_LIST));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    //Initializing our superheroes list
    listSuperHeroes = new ArrayList<>();
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Calling method to get data to fetch data
    getData();

    //Adding an scroll change listener to recyclerview
    recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(this);

    //initializing our adapter
    adapter = new CardAdapter(listSuperHeroes, this);

    //Adding adapter to recyclerview
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

//Add back button to go back
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_back_in, R.anim.activity_back_out);
}

public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_back_in, R.anim.activity_back_out);
    return true;
}

//Request to get json from server we are passing an integer here
//This integer will used to specify the page number for the request ?page = requestcount
//This method would return a JsonArrayRequest that will be added to the request queue
private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount) {
    //Initializing ProgressBar
    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    //Displaying Progressbar
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

    //JsonArrayRequest of volley
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(ConfigMovies.DATA_URL + String.valueOf(requestCount),
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
                    parseData(response);
                    //Hiding the progressbar
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                    Toast.makeText(Movies.this, "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    //Returning the request
    return jsonArrayRequest;
}

//This method will get data from the web api
private void getData() {
    //Adding the method to the queue by calling the method getDataFromServer
    requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(requestCount));
    //Incrementing the request counter
    requestCount++;
}

//This method will parse json data
private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        //Creating the superhero object
        SuperHero superHero = new SuperHero();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            //Getting json
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            //Adding data to the superhero object
            superHero.setImageUrl(json.getString(ConfigMovies.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
            superHero.setName(json.getString(ConfigMovies.TAG_NAME));
            superHero.setPublisher(json.getString(ConfigMovies.TAG_PUBLISHER));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Adding the superhero object to the list
        listSuperHeroes.add(superHero);
    }

    //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

//This method would check that the recyclerview scroll has reached the bottom or not
private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
        int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((GridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//Overriden method to detect scrolling
@Override
public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
    //Ifscrolled at last then
    if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
        //Calling the method getdata again
        getData();
    }
}
}
```

**CardAdapter.java**

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

//Imageloader to load image
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private Context context;

//List to store all superheroes
List<SuperHero> superHeroes;

//Constructor of this class
public CardAdapter(List<SuperHero> superHeroes, Context context){
    super();
    //Getting all superheroes
    this.superHeroes = superHeroes;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.superheroes_list, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //Getting the particular item from the list
    SuperHero superHero =  superHeroes.get(position);

    //Loading image from url
    imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    imageLoader.get(superHero.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.drawable.ic_blank, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

    //Showing data on the views
    holder.imageView.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
    holder.textViewName.setText(superHero.getName());
    holder.textViewPublisher.setText(superHero.getPublisher());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return superHeroes.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    //Views
    public NetworkImageView imageView;
    public TextView textViewName;
    public TextView textViewPublisher;

    //Initializing Views
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
        textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewPublisher = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPublisher);
    }
}
}
```

**Movies.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**superheroes_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewHero"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:text="Publisher"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewPublisher"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let the ViewHolder class implement View.OnClickListener, then move it into CardAdapter class.
2. Call setOnClickListener(this) just after calling super inside ViewHolder constructor like that:

   ```
   public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
       super(itemView);
       itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
       imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
       textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
       textViewPublisher = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPublisher);
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       // here you can get your item by calling getAdapterPosition();
       SuperHero superHero =  superHeroes.get(getAdapterPosition());
   }
   ```

Comment: +1. Although Instead of `getAdapterPosition()` you can keep the object in the viewholder when you retrieve it in `onBindViewHolder`. Saves querying the item for the position in the `onClick` and all. So each viewholder has the object.

Comment: Hi Alex and Uday,

I believe I have done as you instructed, made ViewHolder implement onClick and then set the onClick as you instructed but it's not working as I'm getting errors in Android Studio.

Apologies as I'm 1 week into Android and Java, still learning the basics while grasping the fundamentals.

My CardAdapter class now looks like this (kindly see image capture below):

https://imgur.com/Tu9Lifd
`code`

Comment: Your ViewHolder should extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Comment: Alex I made the changes and I'm not getting any errors now, you were right I was extending viewHolder wrong. After making the changes I now get no errors but when I click on the items I don't see another view opening, nothing happens. 

http://i.imgur.com/0nZeADr.png

Comment: You forget the itemView.setOnClickListener(this) after super.

Comment: Ohh you are right, I had missed that part when copy and pasting. I re-ran the app but the clicks dont do anything, I still see my images and text but no action on click: http://i.imgur.com/vjL9ukN.png does my layout file need clickable action?

Comment: Put   "Log.e("TAG", "position clicked:  " + getAdapterPosition());"   inside onClick()   and tell me if you see that message when you click on card.

Comment: I do see the message on each card click, for example the first card is E/TAG: position clicked: 0 and so on

Comment: Nice! this works, so now you know where user clicked and you have the object.

Comment: How can I pass the objects to a new view with the object showing Image, name and so on? I would need a new view and activity correct?

Comment: Correct, you need new activity. Can you tell me what exactly you want to show on that new activity? are your "SuperHero" object has all that data ready? also from where your image coming from?

Comment: Alex my data (ImageUrl, Name, Publisher) is being pulled from a Mysql database. What I would like is when a card is clicked (which now its clickable) a new "details" activity is started with the data being displayed from the clicked object only. The current "superHero" object should have all the data already, yes.